# T SQL Cumulative Subtraction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I'm using MS SQL Server.

I have the below table:

```
SKU     Shop    WeekNum    ShopPrioirty    Replen   OpeningStock
111     100         1            1           10          5000
111     200         1            2           10          NULL  
111     300         1            3           5           NULL
111     400         1            4           8           NULL

222     100         2            1           20          6000
222     200         2            2           15          NULL
222     300         2            3           12          NULL
222     400         2            4           10          NULL
```

This is the desired result:

```
SKU     Shop    WeekNum    ShopPrioirty    Replen   OpeningStock
111     100         1            1           10          5000
111     200         1            2           10          4990  
111     300         1            3           5           4980
111     400         1            4           8           4975

222     100         2            1           20          6000
222     200         2            2           15          5980
222     300         2            3           12          5965
222     400         2            4           10          5953
```

For a given week, a SKU exists in multiple shops and is assigned a priority.  At Priority 1 the opening stock is assigned.

However, I need to update the Opening Stock (where it is currently NULL) to equal the previous Opening Stock Minus the Previous Replen.

Before I attempt the update, I tried to just do a SELECT

```
SELECT SKU
      ,Shop
      ,WeekNum
      ,StorePriority
      ,Replen
      ,OpeningStock
      ,OpeningStock - Replen OVER (ORDER BY SKU,Shop,WeekNum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Opening
       FROM [table1] t
```

But I receive the error:`Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OVER'.`

Is a running sum the correct way to go?

Would it be best to create a key made up from the SKU\Shop\WeekNum\Priority?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing your aggregate function. I *assume* you mean `- SUM(Replen)` rather than `- Replen`

Comment: If I change it to SUM(Replen) then it only returns 1 OpeningStock figure - I need it to be running

Comment: Given that there is strictly one non-null `OpeningStock` per `SKU`, one option would be `isnull(OpeningStock, sum(OpeningStock) over (partition by SKU) - sum(Replen) over (partition by SKU order by shop, weeknum, priority /* ?? */ rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding))`.

Comment: @GSerg hi - thats not quite correct.  I don't want to minus the the sum of the Replen though.  It just needs to be the previous OpeningStock Minus the Previous Replen.

Comment: @Michael Mathematically it is the same.

Comment: @GSerg It gives the incorrect result though.If you look at the desired result above, the opening stock is just the previous opening stock minus the previous replen, not minus the sum of the replen

Comment: @Michael Mathematically it is the same. The answer below uses exactly that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made a couple of assumptions here on your `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses, but this gets you the result you're after. As you only have a value for `OpeningStock` in the first row for a `SKU`, then I use `FIRST_VALUE` to get the First Value, and then take away all **prior** values of `Replen`:

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(111,100,1,1,10,5000),
                (111,200,1,2,10,NULL),  
                (111,300,1,3,5 ,NULL),
                (111,400,1,4,8 ,NULL),
                (222,100,2,1,20,6000),
                (222,200,2,2,15,NULL),
                (222,300,2,3,12,NULL),
                (222,400,2,4,10,NULL))V(SKU,Shop,WeekNum,ShopPrioirty,Replen,OpeningStock))
SELECT V.SKU,
       V.Shop,
       V.WeekNum,
       V.ShopPrioirty,
       V.Replen,
       V.OpeningStock,
       FIRST_VALUE(V.OpeningStock) OVER (PARTITION BY V.SKU ORDER BY V.ShopPrioirty,V.WeekNum ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) - 
       ISNULL(SUM(V.Replen) OVER (PARTITION BY V.SKU ORDER BY V.ShopPrioirty,V.WeekNum ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS CurrentStock
FROM VTE V;
```

Comment: this looks to be what I'm looking for - out of interest what is the 'VTE' keyword?

Comment: It's not a keyword, @Michael, it's the name I gave the CTE (common Table Expression). I made a typo a few years ago when writing a CTE for a `VALUES` clause, and it was a nice "happy" coincidence that I've used since. I call it a "Values Table Expression"

Comment: that explains it